# How to use two different page number formats in XSL-FO / Apache FOP?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is it possible to have two different page numbering formats on the same page?

I can declare a page-sequence using either of these two methods to get the desired formats

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" id="0" format="1">
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" id="0" format="01">
```

However, I want to have both formats on the same page. One for page numbering, one for a barcode.

The format attribute does not work on `page-number`. I am using Apache FOP 2.1.

```
<fo:page-number format="1" />
<fo:page-number format="01" />
```

Comment: So you have a barcode for the page number plus the page number?  What is the maximum number of pages in a formatted document?

Comment: For example, I have "Page 3 of 9" on the document. Also, I require "0903" within the barcode. So the barcode format needs a leading zero. There will only ever be at most 99 pages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your FO with the human-readable page-number as well as a right-size placeholder for the barcode.
2. Run FOP to generate its area tree XML output.
3. Transform the area tree XML to change the placeholders to be the right markup to generate the correct barcode for each page.
4. Run FOP on the transformed area tree XML to produce the output that you want.

Comment: Yea, that is what I am doing presently. However, I didn't want to have to buffer the output or process things multiple times. Was hoping for a direct solution to such a simple problem.

Comment: It's not necessarily a simple problem when you're trying to do something that wasn't envisaged by the standard and, therefore, isn't implemented by the software.  After all, having two forms of the page number on the same page isn't common (apart from, e.g., page numbers plus letter-folding marks for letters).